# Where to learn Issur V'heter in Brooklyn

Tags: product-recommendation, meat-and-milk, yeshiva-school, semicha

I'm looking for a kollel/group/yeshiva in Brooklyn that is learning Basar Vechalav/Taaruvos. Preferably according to the Ashkenazic Traditions.

It doesn't need to be a semicha program, although that would work as well.

All I can find so far is the Torah Vodaath semicha program but apparently they are currently learning Shechita.

Comment: Just putting out there that the Ohr Reuven Kollel in Monsey is doing Issur Veheter for Semicha this year.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Middlestream and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch Thanks!

Comment: @Eliyahu Thanks for info although not practical for me